# Foundation not working with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, zurb-foundation, create-react-app

I'm building an app with React and create-react-app. I want to use foundation-sites from npm. I do:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import Foundation from 'foundation-sites';
```

At this point even with no further code I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" coming from foundation.js. Normally people fix this with webpack configuration, but with create-react-app I don't have an access to webpack config. I wouldn't like to do `eject`. I tried other solutions like [here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7386) and nothing helped.
Is it actually possible to use Foundation with this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with the code below and it should work.

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;
require('foundation-sites');
```

Comment: Ok, this removed the jQuery error, but now Foundation is just an empty object.

Comment: I think you can import the foundation.min.css file directly.
`import 'foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css';` as follows.
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/201 -  this the the link to include bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, I know I can import css like that, but I need some jQuery based widget from Foundation :-)

Comment: Alright, @hmachahary it turns out you were very close :-)
Instead of 

`var Foundation = require('foundation-sites');` 
I just had to do 
`require('foundation-sites');` without a variable declaration.
And then something like
`const modal = new window.Foundation.Reveal(jquery('#error-modal'));`
works

Comment: Hi @hmachahary It works fine but the issue is when you try to build the optimised version it fails like 
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/js/main.7d12ffea.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected character '`' [./~/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.core.js:24,0][static/js/main.7d12ffea.js:10682,124]

error Command failed with exit code 1.
Do you have any idea how to build it without ejecting the babel config?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning jQuery to window. Preferably, this should be done in entrypoint file.

```
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```